# Filter in linQ c# with dynamic properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, properties

I have a list of properties

```
string[] strings =
{
    "State", "Name","Location"
};
```

They are all in Test object with type string, I need to loop throw them first and filter the data when the property equal "OK"

Here is my code snippet

```
for (int x=0;x<strings.Length;x++)
{
    // PropertyDescriptor prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Test)).Find(strings[x],true);                                               

    var miss = _unityOfWork.TestRepository.Get(i =>
                   i.GetType().GetProperty(strings[x]).Equals("OK") )
                   .Select().toList()
```

this code returns the following exception:

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo GetRuntimeProperty(System.Type, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

I need to filter the list with the property name form the array

Comment: What is exactly your TestRepository? How is it implemented?

Comment: I think you meant to say _when the property **value** equal "OK"_, right?

Comment: @EduardMalakhov it is inherited from GenericRepository

Comment: LINQ is trying to translate the expression `i.GetType().GetProperty(strings[x]).Equals("OK")` into a database query (usually SQL), which is the `store expression`-part from the error. However the first database that supports .NET reflection has yet to be invented...

Comment: @wdosanjos right, the Test class has 3 properties i need to validate when those equal to "OK"

Comment: As @PeterB pointed out, that is not possible in pure LINQ. You would have to first obtain all entities from the repository and then filter them using your reflection-based expression.

Comment: @PeterB any workaround for that .. i have now to write this Linq 3 times for each one ?

Comment: @abdou-telb does `strings` have to be dynamic? Or they are always the same ("State", "Name","Location")?  If they have to be dynamic, the solution will require the manipulation of dynamic expressions.

Comment: @wdosanjos they will alywas the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would probably do it... plain and simple, without reflection, and the switch has two functions: (1) to guard against unknown fields, (2) to apply the proper condition for every case.

```
var strings = new[] { "State", "Name", "Location" };

var result = _unityOfWork.TestRepository.GetAll().AsQueryable();
// you may need to tweak the above before it works

foreach (var field in strings)
{
    switch (field)
    {
        case "State":
            result = result.Where(x => x.State == "OK");
            break;
        case "Name":
            result = result.Where(x => x.Name == "OK");
            break;
        case "Location":
            result = result.Where(x => x.Location == "OK");
            break;
    }
}

return result;   // if needed, add .ToList() or .ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially do the following:

```
public string ValidateProperty<T>(T parameter)
{
     var properties = typeof(...).GetProperties();
     foreach(var property in properties)
          if(property == parameter)
              return "OK";

     return "FAIL";
}   

var content = collection.Get().Where(property => ValidateProperty(property.Name.Value) == "OK" && ValidateProperty(property.State.Value) == "OK");
```

Didn't have time to check the syntax, but this should allow you to compare all.  The pitfall, is it will be generating a `PropertyInfo` array every call.  An idea or a different approach, not sure how feasible it will be for your implementation though.

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP indicated that the properties are always the same, please try this:

```
var miss = _unitOfWork.TestRepository
                      .Where(m => m.State == "OK" || m.Name == "OK" || m.Location == "OK");
```

Comment: I need a row per test per valid property

Comment: Changed `&&` by `||` to address your test requirement.

Comment: still has issues when projection can't get where exactly the condition occurs

Answer (score -1):

You could do this (not sure about the exact syntax, but the idea):

```
var miss = _unityOfWork.TestRepository.Get()

                   .Where(i => i.GetType().GetProperty(strings[x]).Equals("OK"))
                   .toList()
```

**EDIT:**
The correct option would be something like

```
var miss = _unityOfWork.TestRepository
                .ToList()
                .Where(i => i.GetType().GetProperty(strings[x]).Equals("OK"))
                .toList()
```

Comment: Thanks ... but it still the same

Comment: @AbdouTelb sorry, I've lost the ToList call in the middle.